# access_refused on rabbitmq server with spring-boot-1.1.3, fine with 1.0.1

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have a working client application under spring-boot 1.0.1, but when I update the spring-boot version to 1.1.3.RELEASE, I get a periodic Connection Reset stack trace on the client, and I can see the following log on the server:

=INFO REPORT==== 3-Jul-2014::10:57:55 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.3945.0> (192.168.100.14:64049 -> 192.168.100.116:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Jul-2014::10:57:58 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.3945.0> (192.168.100.14:64049 -> 192.168.100.116:5672):
{handshake_error,opening,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "access to vhost 'dev-lmu' refused for user 'hermes'",
                             'connection.open'}}

I think it's fair to set the premise that permission issues are out of the question, because the app works under boot 1.0.1

I use RabbitMQ 3.3.4

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Are you using Spring AMQP to connect to Rabbit or using Rabbit's Java client directly? Either way, it'd be helpful to know the versions of the Rabbit-related dependencies in the working and failing cases.

Comment: Have you upgraded your rabbitmq too? 3.3.x doesn't allow `guest` to connect on anything except `localhost` (by default).

Comment: Oh, I see your user is 'hermes'; hmmmm...

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I use spring-boot-starter-amqp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was bug in boot but it has since been fixed (upgrade to 1.1.4)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/ad1636fd349b2e6636837d98af1ba1d07500ec9f#diff-19dc1e9553b1605c75168e38dcbc9477

Removed the leading '/' from the virtual host.

The relevant boot issue is: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1206

Comment: Hi, is there a workaround I can use to make it work, or should I just wait for 1.1.4 ? The project is not in production yet, so I still have the choice to name my virtual host without a leading slash.

Comment: Unfortunately not; originally, only vHosts that had a leading `/` were supported; someone added a "fix" to allow vHosts without a `/` but broke vHosts that do have a `/`. Unfortunately, I don't see a workaround other than using a vHost without a `/` until 1.1.4 is available.

Comment: Well, I'm still in the position to do that. I'll lose the leading slash. Thanks a ton!